# Voltage level detection circuitry

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I have a designed circuit board that has a problem with its start up sequences. The problem is that the voltage ramps up (could be as low as from 0V to 5V) so slowly that the chip won't physically turn on.

I want to add an independent circuit board that will act as a bridge to solve that problem. The circuit will collect the voltage from that slowly ramping voltage and once it hits 5V it will have a switch to instantly release the 5V.

The flow will be :

> [some input voltage] --> [voltage regulator]--->[some detection
> circuit that know when it hit 5V mark] ----> [release the voltage]

I have no idea how to design the detection circuit.

Edit:

[This is the voltage regulator I'm using (TOS54302.)](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54302.pdf)

[The chip is a pMDDL2450 2.4GHz data link RF module.](http://www.microhardcorp.com/brochures/pMDDL2450.Brochure.Rev.1.0.0.pdf)

Comment: (1) What chip "won't turn on"? (2) "0 V to 5 V" doesn't tell us the ramp up rate. (3) Have you got a schematic for your power supply and your circuit board?

Comment: You've provided a "flow" but you really don't understand what's available and what they "usual" approaches should be. So you should NOT try and coerce a particular "flow." Instead, you should spend all of your time describing exactly what you want to achieve. What "chip" is having problems? What voltage source is "slow" in ramping up? Is it essentially unregulated? How slow is it? What current compliance do you require for your regulated voltage output? Etc. Just focus on as much *known* details; stuff you are sure of and understand. Let the rest follow and don't coerce a direction.

Comment: Look up "power-on reset" chips, and you won't have to design one.

Comment: The chip im using is microhard MDDL2450

Answer (score 1):

You would be best to use an inexpensive accurate reset chip - they contain a voltage reference, a comparator and a timer to force the system into reset at a very low voltage and maintain the reset until the supply voltage has been within specifications for some substantial time (like 200ms). If the supply voltage dips they assert the reset again quickly, and you can arrange it so the reset is asserted before the voltage falls out of spec for your system. There is also usually some hysteresis.

While you could design your own, the requirement that it work from a very low voltage makes it difficult to use simple building block ICs like comparators, and they are usually fairly accurate in terms of the voltage thresholds, so precision parts or adjustments might be necessary.

Cheap reset circuits that use something like an RC network are a major cause of systems failing to power up properly, or to recover from brief blips in the supply.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with some kind of DIY solution, with no need for fancy power management ICs, or clever reset protocols, then this may help:

[image]

This was my response to a very similar Reddit question. It operates by comparing 3.6V to some fraction of the input supply voltage, determined by R1 and R3. If the input voltage is high enough that this threshold is exceeded, a MOSFET switch is closed, to connect the load to directly to the input source.

There is some hysteresis introduced by R5, to keep the transition sharp and clean, and somewhat immune to input noise.

In this configuration, the "switch" is closed when the input voltage reaches 5.4V, which is not exactly what you need, but you may adjust that threshold by changing R1 or R3, such that:

Vin x R3 / (R1 + R3) = 3.6V

My advice would be to place this at the *input* side of the regulator, and configure its threshold to be slightly over 5V plus the drop-out voltage of the regulator.

As it is, this circuit may not be able to provide anything over a few hundred milliamps, since there is no gate drive circuitry to ensure a gate-source voltage sufficiently large to switch on Q1 hard enough, but it should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Some low-cost ICs rely on internal POR (power-on-reset) circuitry to start operating. And they may not have a dedicated RESET pin. This kind of POR circuitry usually requires certain Vin ramp to work properly. For example, Microchip states the ramp rate of 50mV/ms for PIC16 familiy, which is about 100 ms ramp time. The TPS54302 has the output ramp time of about 4 ms (10-90%), which should easily fit the bill, unless something else is designed-in.

If the 4-5 ms for 5-V rail is too slow for the IC in use, you might need to design-in a high-side power switch controlled by a simple RC delay. Or maybe just reducing some unnecessary-high bypass capacitance on board will fix the start-up issue. The details are in your numbers, which you decided to omit from your question.

Comment: The chip is Microhard pMDDL2450
http://www.microhardcorp.com/brochures/pMDDL2450.Brochure.Rev.1.0.0.pdf

Comment: @JackVu, I can see a little problem here. This is a RF radio module. RF units usually work with high-power bursts, and usually require substantial bypass capaciance, 1000s of uF. I can see that this might slow the voltage ramp significantly. If this is the case, an external switch won't work. You need to identify a reset circuit/pin for the module, and put a dedicated POR ICs (aka "voltage monitor") to generate a delayed RESET.